# What would happen and stop me from using smaller beings?

Tags: biology, creature-design

A problem I've run into is the use of ultra massive beings due to the effects of the square-cube law which means that I cannot within the current laws of physics have the world I envision. My world contains massive, island size ,tortoise-like creatures which walk through shallow coastal areas. These creatures are used as living space by sentient creatures with intelligence equal to humans or better.

However that does not work so what I propose instead is the having the tortoises normal size for a pet and the sentients proportionally sized. Is this possible? Are there any requirements?

Clarifying island size: The Isle of Wight.

Comment: If your sentient creatures are smaller, you start running into brain size constraints. "Human or better" intelligence requires a pretty large brain. (But I love the idea of sentient animals living on the backs of really big tortoises!)

Comment: @BrettFromLA I was worried that this would be a problem.

Comment: You don't really explain why giant turtles won't work.  They just need someway to support their bulk.  If they are in coastal seas already, part of that support will come from the water they are half way submerged in.

Comment: @Green I have another question on this if you wish to answer I will work on a link

Comment: @Mendeleev, I'm just interested in your explanation for why giant turtles won't work.  Continents float on an "ocean of magma".  Why couldn't giant turtles (if built correctly) not work on "oceans of water"?

Comment: @Green The heavy upper bodies crushing the lower halves, if you're able to make it work please answer the other question.

Comment: There is also a scaling issue with brains, the smaller the animal the larger the brain has to be proportionally. a big body does not require a  larger brain, so larger creatures can spare resources to make the brain bigger for other reasons. so say a housecat sized human would have a huge head like a toddler.

Comment: @Mendeleev Honestly your best bet is to make strange turtles, only make them look superficially like turtles. Use exotic but real materials for their structure and handwave the metabolism with some new unknown metabolism like a biological nuclear reactor. Maybe they need to stay in the ocean becasue they need to constantly consume water as a coolant. go for a softer science.

Comment: Why would your island-size tortoise not work? Square-cube law does not outlaw large creatures, it just forces you to start using better materials so the square-cube law becomes a problem later on. Your body contains mostly Carbon and Water. Cells are capable of building large molecules... And there is a Grey area around Graphene and Carbon Nanotubes you can use to justify the strength. If the tortoise is able to grow high-grade 3D Graphene structures for a skeleton it can grow enormous (Graphene could be space elevator material), and water-based spidersilk a perfect tendon replacement.

Answer (score 6):

Tiny sentience runs into the problem of brain size. While human medicine doesn't know everything about the brain, we know enough to identify regions that do certain tasks. Below a given threshold, there isn't enough space for all the regions, so with human physiology, it seems clear tiny humans would have to give up functionality.

But... do neurons have to be so large? Transistors of past decades are giant compared to the ones we use in computers today. Maybe neurons can be implemented smaller? (I am dodging the question of whether transistors are sufficient to replicate human intelligence... that's a topic for another day/forum.) Evolution has never to my knowledge had a reason to select for smaller neurons in humans. Maybe they can be made more space efficient without loss of functionality. That's an open question for science, so far as I know, so you're free to posit what you like.

Alternatively, if the braincase gets smaller, you might get different brain structure. Perhaps the limbic system stretches down the spine. Or the thyroid is near the gut. By distributing pieces, you might free up room in a tiny skull. From the outside, they'd still look human. Downside: injuries that to us are healable might not be to them. "Oh, a bolt through the arm. We can stop the blood, but that's where his autonomic systems are controlled from. I'm afraid he forgot how to breathe." That sort of thing. The torso/skull's advantage is it gives us one "critical region" to protect, and we can afford loss of limbs. The more the limbs have critical infrastructure, the worse it gets.

So, yes, there are ways to have tiny sentients that seem human. Just don't look inside or expect human doctors to treat them!

Comment: Well that is a great answer thank you, it gives a great plan, you may of overlooked the great care I took in not saying humans to allow for differences.

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't sure if you were excluding humans or trying to be inclusive of a world with humans and other sentient beings, so I covered bases. :-)

Comment: Non neuron based life is tricky, because we have so little prior art to work from -- all known sentient animals are neuron based.  But it does offer great potential in removing limiting factors that exist in our world today!

Comment: tiny neurons don't exist in humans but they do exist, fairy wasp have very small neurons, The entire animal is smaller than an amoeba. many neurons lack a nucleus and is more reminiscent of a fungus than a normal set of neurons. http://blogs.discovermagazine.com/notrocketscience/2011/11/30/how-fairy-wasps-cope-with-being-smaller-than-amoebas/#.WHlwH_krLIU

Comment: @John Are those neurons able to functionally replicate what human neurons do?

Comment: As far as we can tell they work as well as normal neurons, but since they were just discovered it has not been studied in depth yet.

Answer (score 1):

One thing that I would consider is that, usually, small mammalians tend to have a fast metabolism, hence, die more quickly than humans. If your story lasts for several decades, you might have to think about it.